# How can I create this 3D text video presentation?

Tags: video

I don't have much clue about 3D modeling or Animation. I'm good at programming & Graphic designing though. Thing is I want to do something like shown in this 15second video:

To be more specific, I need some 3D text as shown in the video as a slideshow. I need to create a 15-30 second video of that kind. Then I'll also have to record voice over it. That I can do in video editing.

If you know a quick tutorial of this kind, that would be a great help too. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [3D Extruder](http://aescripts.com/3d-extruder/) plugin/script for After Effects CS5.5 to create the 3D text, then I'll create a camera to animate the movement.

The tutorials plus network has a lot of [great tutorials](http://ae.tutsplus.com/articles/news/3d-text-in-after-effects/). Though I've never actually watched any of the ones on 3D text...